# UITableView With Parse Query Not Loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, parse-platform

So I have a UITableView and a Parse query, and the query is able to retrieve the objects from parse. But the TableView is no showing them.

Here is my code I'll explain more below:

```
- (PFQuery *)query {
    NSLog(@"hello");
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.


    // Query for posts near our current location.

    // Get our current location:
    //CLLocation *currentLocation = [self.dataSource currentLocationForWallPostsTableViewController:self];
    CLLocationAccuracy filterDistance = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:PAWUserDefaultsFilterDistanceKey];

    // And set the query to look by location
    PFGeoPoint *point = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:40.941984
                                               longitude:-72.88712399999997];
    [query whereKey:PAWParsePostLocationKey nearGeoPoint:point withinKilometers:PAWMetersToKilometers(filterDistance)];
    [query includeKey:PAWParsePostUserKey];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu users.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
            self.myArray = objects;
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];


    NSLog(@"work");

    return query;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return self.myArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSLog(@"yy");
    NSString *kk= [object objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSLog(@"%@",kk);
    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"text"];

    return cell;
}
```

**Two things that I have found out that may be causing the issue is:**

1. `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` is being called before the query, which doesn't make sense to me.
2. And because that is being called before the query the array.count is 0;

So I don't understand why that line would be called before the the query. If you have any suggestions please let me know!

**Update** This is being called three times, and the second nslog is not being called.

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        NSLog(@"Fsa");
        return self.myArray.count;
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu .", (unsigned long)self.myArray.count);

    }
```

In my .h

```
UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

[image]

Comment: What do you have against ParseQueryTableViewController?

Comment: @soulshined Nothing haha. I was using it but stopped because it didn't allow the customization I wanted.

Comment: And your calling this query in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @soulshined No it's in it's own separate method.

Comment: I'm feeling a bit too sick right now to write out a full comment but you're getting some poor answers... The problem lies in the fact that you're both using the - (PFQuery *)query method to populate your table and doing and asynchronous query within it to get the number of object `self.myArray` to populate the number of rows. That's the issue. That's why you have 0 rows. If no one's able to help you I'll help once I feel a bit better.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Okay thank you. Feel better.

Comment: Jack, could you post your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, please?

Comment: @LyndseyScott Feel better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
```

returns a query which automatically populates the PFObject in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:object:` in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
```

What you've done, however, is perform the `query` within your `queryForTable` method. (1) You don't need to perform the query, you simply need to return it, but (2) it seems as if you're strictly performing that query in order to populate `self.myArray` which you then which to use as a return value in `numberOfRowsInSection:`. The problem with #2 is that the query you're performing in `queryForTable` is performed asynchronously, so `self.myArray` may still be empty by the time `numberOfRowsInSection:` is called. So that's what's happening -- `self.myArray.count` = 0 and  therefore `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` wouldn't be called being called.

But the biggest problem of all, #3, is that `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object` can only be used in a `PFQueryTableViewController` so you'll have to use a query and the standard `UITableView` delegate methods instead.

Try this instead:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSLog(@"hello");
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];

    // Query for posts near our current location.

    // Get our current location:
    //CLLocation *currentLocation = [self.dataSource currentLocationForWallPostsTableViewController:self];
    CLLocationAccuracy filterDistance = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:PAWUserDefaultsFilterDistanceKey];

    // And set the query to look by location
    PFGeoPoint *point = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:40.941984
                                               longitude:-72.88712399999997];
    [query whereKey:PAWParsePostLocationKey nearGeoPoint:point withinKilometers:PAWMetersToKilometers(filterDistance)];
    [query includeKey:PAWParsePostUserKey];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu users.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
            self.myArray = objects;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.myArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSLog(@"yy");
    NSString *kk= [[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSLog(@"%@",kk);
    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do I still need tableView:numberOfRowsInSection? I'm using a tableView in a regular viewcontroller.

Comment: @Jack In using the - (PFQuery *)query method, did you actually mean to use a - (PFQuery *)queryForTable method instead?

Comment: @Jack Cool... That makes more sense. I don't think `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` is required (I don't think number of sections is required either but I left that in there), but you can try my update and see what happens. If you really wanted to use `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` though you can get wait for a response from `objectsDidLoad:` and set `self.array` in that method.

Comment: Okay I added all that but now it crashes and I'm getting this: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Feed tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe832d46e10'

Comment: @Jack OK, we'll delete numberOfRowsInSection: then... How about now?

Comment: Same thing even after I deleted it.

Comment: @Jack Have you set the delegate? Is it included at the top of the class? And is the table view a UITableView or PFTableView and is the delegate UITableViewDelegate or PFTableViewDelegate?

Comment: Look at the bottom of the question I added my .h and a image.It's a UIViewController with a UITableView.

Comment: @Jack Oh... You're trying to perform Parse methods on a UITableView. You can't do that. You should change it to a PFTableView.

Comment: Well that explains a lot. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Jack Just looked into it and you can only use `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {` with `PFQueryTableViewController`'s so you'll have to use a query and a the standard UITableView delegate methods instead. I'll re-write my answer.

Comment: Okay thank you I will get back to you tomorrow on that.

Comment: @Jack No problem. Glad it works. :) I'm feeling much much better today though, so if you continue to have any issues with this particular code, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will let you know. Glad you are feeling better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu users.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        self.myArray = objects;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: I just tried this and I it crashed saying:'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' But I have the dataSource and delegates linked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the correct solution for the problem in your question: the `UITableView` is now trying to display the data. You need to make sure `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns a valid cell, but this is a different problem. I doubt your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object:` method is called.

Comment: @ThomasMüller This isn't the correct answer unfortunately and tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: isn't being called because numberOfRowsInSection is returning 0... I'll try to write up an answer because I think this question's quickly going down a rabbit hole...

Comment: @LyndseyScott With this answer the tableView is told to reload its data on the main thread. To me it looks like `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning something greater than 0, then `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is being called and results in an error because (I guess) it's not properly implemented and doesn't return a cell.

Comment: @ThomasMüller The OP is using this method though: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object`  which expects to be populated by the results of a query, but that method will only work in a PFQueryTableViewController, which the OP is NOT using. There are many issues with the code and this answer doesn't really cover them.

Comment: @LyndseyScott OK, I see. I have never used `PFQueryTableViewController`, and looking at their API docs for a minute I agree that a few things seem wrong with the code. You mind if I give a crack at an answer? Feels like stealing it from you, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly calling it in viewDidLoad. Provided self.myArray = objects doesn't return nil this should suffice. It will force it to load circumventing other methods loading first:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    [self locationQuery];
}

-(PFQuery *)locationQuery {

    CLLocationAccuracy filterDistance = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:PAWUserDefaultsFilterDistanceKey];
    PFGeoPoint *point = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:40.941984
                                           longitude:-72.88712399999997];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];
    [query whereKey:PAWParsePostLocationKey nearGeoPoint:point withinKilometers:PAWMetersToKilometers(filterDistance)];
    [query includeKey:PAWParsePostUserKey];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // The find succeeded.
                NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu users.", (unsigned long)objects.count); 
                self.myArray = objects;
                //OR : 
                self.myArray = [objects valueForKey:@"NameOfParse.comClassColumnHere"];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
     }];
        return query;
}
```

Additionally, your cell.textLabel.text is referencing something that doesn't exist..

> NSString *kk= [object objectForKey:@"text"];
>       NSLog(@"%@",kk);
>       // Configure the cell
>       cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"text"];

what is this? if you want it to be the array you queried you have to do :

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: @Jack I asked that. If you mean you have different query just name the method something else, it doesn't matter.

Comment: yes the names are different, but I already had something in my viewDidLoad calling the query.

Comment: that code is relevant, show it @Jack or simply delete it, and do the void method I explained.

Comment: I added the code you provide but I'm still getting the same issue. Look at the update on the question.

Comment: @Jack is self.myArray = objects; returning values? NSLog self.myArray in stead of the number

Comment: Yea that retrieves 1, which is correct but if I put the same nslog in the numberOfRowsInSection it doesn't even print, that method is still being called before the query. @soulshined

Comment: @Jack see my edited answer, you have reload the table but your cell label references something that isn't shown in the code... if your mission is to reload it with the array you queried you have to set it to that. If this doesn't work I can't help you my friend. Sorry

Comment: @Jack additionally, if you want the object for key you should do it in the query as well. I have shown an example in my answer

Comment: when I add the line of code to reload the tableView it crashes with this: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
And, yes the dataSource is linked in IB.

Comment: @Jack yes I explained it at the bottom of my answer. [object objectForKey:] is not correct nor is it referencing anything

Comment: @Jack your table won't reload if you don't have an accurately called cell, which yours is not. But you have to reload the table after your query or else how will it know that it received information.

Comment: How should I go about getting the retrieved objects from the query onto the cells?

Comment: @Jack at the bottom of my answer is code for setting the cells title from your queried array

Comment: Okay when I added that, I still get this: '*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.48/UITableView.m:7344' & '*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: @Jack That's an indicator something isn't set properly in storyboard. Check I know you said you set it, but verify the file owner is receiving dataSource and delegate and there could possibly be missing a IBOutlet connection that is no longer connected

Comment: They are defiantly set in the storyboard, just checked.